# How can I set mime mapping to a file served as static content by jetty-runner

Tags: jetty

I want to place my cache.manifest in my web site but it should have "text/cache-manifest" as mime type. I'd like not to pack the static content in a war if possible. It's my first time deploying a web app so I don't know if I can put a web.xml along with the files and serve them like this:

> sudo java  -cp jetty-runner-9.2.13.v20150730.jar
>   org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner  --port 80 --path /
>   site/MyStaticWebSite

without packing it into a war.

In Apache I would write this into .htaccess :

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest
```

But how i can set it into jetty-runner?

Comment: Is your application using a `WEB-INF/web.xml`?

Comment: I rather serve it without a .war, it is only static content.

Answer (score 1):

I should place a WEB-INF directory inside the root of the served content with a web.xml file that contains:

```
<web-app>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>manifest</extension>
    <mime-type>text/cache-manifest</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Then restart jetty-runner, and check :

`wget --server-response --spider http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX/file.manifest`

I get :

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 16:16:39 GMT
  Content-Type: text/cache-manifest
  Last-Modified: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 15:58:57 GMT
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Content-Length: 143
  Server: Jetty(9.2.13.v20150730)
Length: 143 [text/cache-manifest]
Remote file exists.
```